# Using \begin{collect*} in a new \newenviroment

Tags: errors, environments

I'm not terrible experienced with latex, an I'm trying to wrap up the \begin{collect*} command with some common arguments used into its own enviroment, but I'm having trouble getting the whole thing to work. The issue only shows inside a custom enviroment. A minimal example that shows this example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{collect}


\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{dup}{ m }
  {  \begin{collect*}{#1dupcollection}{}{}{}{}
  }
  {
  \end{collect*}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{dup}{atest}
content...
\end{dup}

\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is: File ended while scanning use of \@tempa

I have tried looking for a solution but had no luck finding one. I'm sure someone here can assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the package documentation (PDF)](http://ftp.cstug.cz/pub/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sauerj/collect.pdf):

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}

\usepackage{collect}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dup}[1]{%
  \definecollection{#1dupcollection}%
  \@nameuse{collect*}{#1dupcollection}{}{}{}{}%
}{%
  \@nameuse{endcollect*}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dup}{atest}
content...
\end{dup}

\end{document}
```